# Conversion from cartesian to spherical coordinates and floating-point imprecision

Tags: precision, trigonometry, numeric, atan2, atan

I need to convert cartesian to spherical coordinates, but my implementation is suffering from floating-point imprecision. Here's what I'm doing until now:

```
template<typename RealType>
Point3<RealType> cartesian_to_spherical(Point3<RealType> const& p)
{
    auto const &x = p.x, &y = p.y, &z = p.z;
//  (x, y, z) = (r sin θ cos ϕ, r sin θ sin ϕ, r cos θ)

    auto const r_squared = x * x + y * y + z * z;
    if (r_squared > 0)
    {
        auto const r = std::sqrt(r_squared);
        auto const theta = std::acos(z / r);

        if (0 < theta && theta < pi<RealType>)
        {
            RealType phi;
            if (x > 0)
            {
                phi = std::atan(y / x);
                if (y < 0)
                    phi += 2 * pi<RealType>;
            }
            else if (x < 0)
                phi = pi<RealType> + std::atan(y / x);
            else // x == 0
                phi = y > 0 ? phi = pi<RealType> / 2 : 3 * pi<RealType> / 2;

            return { r, theta, phi };
        }
        else
            throw std::domain_error("theta = 0 or theta = pi");
    }
    else
        throw std::domain_error("r = 0");
}
```

For example, if `cartesian_to_spherical` is invoked with `RealType = float` and `p = {.000157882227f, .000284417125f, 1 }`, then `r_squared` is `1.00000012` and its square root `r` is computed to `1` (which is obviously wrong). As a consequence, `theta` is computed to `0`, while the correct value would be `0.000325299694...`.

Can we improve the code such that these computations are more accurate?

(You may want to take note of the conversion described [here](http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Color_and_Radiometry/Working_with_Radiometric_Integrals.html#IntegralsoverSphericalCoordinates) using `std::atan2`. However, if I'm not missing something, it yields the wrong result if `std::sin(theta)` is 0 (i.e. `theta` is 0 or `pi`) and it also computes `theta` to `0` in the example.)

Comment: "r_squared is 1.00000012 and its square root r is computed to 1'. Are you using `float` mapped to IEEE-754 `binary32` (a.k.a. single precision) for this computation? This is accurate to only about 7 decimal digits, and the encoding closest to sqrt(1.00000012f) is 1.

Comment: You might want to look into use of `hypot` and `atan2`. Untested: `r = hypot (hypot (x, y), z); theta = atan2 (y, x); phi = atan2 (hypot (x, y), z);`

Comment: You start with a value 0.000157882227 assuming that the unit is a meter then you have a measurement that you are claiming to be accurate down to 1/1000th of a nano meter, smaller than an atom.. If you use realistic values at best to the mm then `{.000157882227, .000284417125, 1 } = {0,0,1}`. You say *"...computed to 1 (which is obviously wrong)."* Not at all the error is not in the math, it is in the input.